# Regular Expression too general

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the regular expression:

```
"(al|sf|sa|sc|nrc|nrc form|doe|doe f|lsi|doe form psd f|doe al f)?[\\s\\-\\.]*[\\d]{3,6}[\\s\\-\\.]*[\\w]{1,4}"
```

I do not want purely numeric strings such as "2001" to pass this test, but "2001" is passing for this regular expression. Why? How can I fix this?

Comment: Does the first group have to be optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?` and `*` parts are optional, so the only required part of the regex is

```
\d{3,6}\w{1,4}
```

`\w` includes digits, so it passes because 2001 is 3 `\d` and 1 `\w`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add negative lookahead like this:

```
(?!^\\d+$)
```